# Declare folder as language neutral in VS2017 build for the Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am building an application for UWP in Visual Studio 2017 (it is actually a Unity game, the solution is exported from Unity). During build, I get the following warnings, and the files which are reported as such do not show up in the final appxupload file, and thus cannot be found at runtime:

```
1>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : warning PRI263: 0xdef01051 - No default or neutral resource given for 'Files/Data/GI/level1/ca51e77bb6146d425e0c9319844929a0.vis'. The application may throw an exception for certain user configurations when retrieving the resources.
```

There is a warning message for the resource situation in general, which reads like this:

```
1>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : warning PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found for language(s) 'be,ca,fa' but no resources found for default language(s): ''. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899
```

The languages that are reported as such are in folders which have language iso codes (for example, in the error message, the file is actually in the folder Files/Data/GI/level1/**ca**/). However, these folders are NOT language specific, they are named this way due to an internal indexing scheme of Unity which I cannot change.

So, what I am asking is this: How, and where, can I configure Visual Studio or whatever part of MSBuild is responsible to NOT treat these folders as language-specific? Or is there any other solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set your file as content file in Visual Studio when build? Right click your file in VS and then see it's build action, if it is set as content then it will build as content file. By the way, you can also make sure that you have set it to copy always when building.

Comment: Thanks, but they were already set to "content". See below for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround. Part of the build is a call to makepri.exe which creates the Package Resource Index (PRI) files which more or less contain a directory of files in the build. Makepri, by default, looks for language-named folders and splits the build along the languages it finds - which moves the language-specific files into resource packs.

Luckily, this behavior can be configured, as is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/build-resources-into-app-package) - makepri can be instructed to just place everything in one big resource file instead of splitting up. This is achieved by editing the .csproj file, and adding the following two lines to the configuration section for Master|x64:

```
<AppxBundleAutoResourcePackageQualifiers>
   DXFeatureLevel
</AppxBundleAutoResourcePackageQualifiers>

<AppxDefaultResourceQualifiers>
   Language=en-us;de-de;es-es
</AppxDefaultResourceQualifiers>
```

The first tag disables auto-language qualifiers (since "**Language**" is MISSING from the list of qualifiers). Since languages are now no longer auto-detected, they must be explicitly listed (second tag).

I've not found a way to do what I originally wanted - specifying that certain folders should not be considered language-specific - but this works for me.